# Selecting dynamic, filtered range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to select a dynamic range of filtered data that spans from col. A: col. J without selecting the header (in row 1). From there I need to copy and paste it into a new sheet where I will manipulate it further, but I cannot come up with an efficient or functional way to do this. Based on some code I found on another forum I was able to select all of the "visable cells" in a single column, but I am running into issues trying to select the whole range. I am still very new to vba so forgive my syntax, but my code posted below was an attempt to itterate through Rows.Count and i which was an integer 1-10. If you have any advice on how to do this better and more efficiently I would really appreciate it.

```
Sub SelectVisibleInColD()
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Integer
    Set i = 1
Do While i <= 10

    With ActiveSheet
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        If lRow < 3 Then Exit Sub
        .Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lRow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    End With

 i = i + 1
 Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select a range by using `Range` property of `ActiveSheet`. You already have the last row and you know that the header is in the first row, so your range starts from position `A2` and goes to the last row of column `J`

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:J"&lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

If you want to copy this range, use `Copy` function like

```
yourRangeAsAbove.Copy
```

This function only moves the selection to memory, to paste it, build your destination range and call `PasteSpecial` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer googling my issue for: deleting of filtered selection in vba.
However trying your answer **&lRow** gives me an runtime error 1004, application-defineed or object-defined error

I got around it with this
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:G" & **Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)**.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete

For those that may also get the same issue.